# JQuery mouseup outside window – possible?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I am trying to accomplish a rudimentary drag. On mousedown the item starts dragging, but not at the same speed as the mouse, so i continue dragging when the mouse is outside the window, but if the mouse is not over the page i can't get mouseup events.

I can see other pages do this so i know it is possible. Appreciate any help.

**Edit: eg**

Play any video on Vimeo http://vimeo.com/19831216 make sure the window is small enough on your screen with space above it, then drag the video's progress bar left and right, now move the cursor outside the top edge of the window while still dragging left/right - see? Now release mouse button while still outside of the window - dragging ends and video continues playing.

Note: Vimeo has an option to use a flash player or HTML5 player and this is with the html5 player.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You actually **can** get the mouseup outside of the browser's window.

It worked for me at least.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).mouseup(function(){
       alert('mouse up'); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fFeJ6/

Working on Chrome 10 on Ubuntu Maverick.

Comment: Thanks, simple eh? I was using 'body' instead of window.

Comment: yeah and it was actually working on firefox 4, but firefox requires `alert()` to have an argument passed to fire and I forgot that. Cheers!

Comment: I tested on windows and mac, this code works. Just add a string to the alert function for some browsers.

Comment: Could you paste the code into the answer? Save people that extra click. :)

Comment: On firefox (24.0/windows) it works fine for left mouse button but doesn't trigger for middle or right buttons (assuming right handed, I guess). Chrome does a better job and works for all 3 buttons!

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent! Working in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac. Though curiously, in Firefox if you release the mouse over the Developer Tools pane, the mouseup event doesn't get delivered.

Comment: @thenickdude I'm having same problem in Firefox, mouseup event not firing. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: You mean the jsfiddle doesn't work for you when you hold down the button inside the preview area (bottom right square) and release it outside the browser window? Are you maybe testing using the right mouse button? Many browsers don't deliver mouseup events for right (or middle) mouse button drags that end outside the window.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases in Chrome. Example: codepen.io/thdoan/pen/jwLPjL (click image, drag up to the top frame, release).

Answer (score 1):

you can not track mouse events outside the browser window with javascript.

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672142/javascript-event-when-mouse-leaves-browser-window) you can only check if the mouse leaves the window.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the very useful link, it seems to suggest that it is possible, and you are saying it isn't?

Comment: maybe its possible in flash but not with javascript

Comment: Really? There is no flash on the Vimeo page i am looking at.

Comment: really really? try to inspect the video itself with firebug

Comment: yes really really really really - i dont have any flash player installed. I am on OSX safari - again, no flash installed whatsoever.

Comment: I assume Vimeo uses HTML5 `<video>` where possible/mandatory.

Comment: Please support your answer with more definitive evidence.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe catch the mouseout event and then call your mouseup function from there:

```
$(window).mouseout(function() { $(item).mouseup(); });
```

Comment: I do not want to mouseup when leaving the window. I want to continue capturing drag events outside of the window.

Comment: This is kinda the opposite of what i want to do

Comment: @hooleyhoop that's not possible with JS. You can, however, monitor events from any window using something like AutoHotkey.

Comment: The problem with this is that the user might not have let go. They could have dragged something very temporarily too far out the window then back, then it's lost and not being dragged. Why can't javascript just tell me if the mouse pointer is currently down? (when on the window)