# Meteor: bind events outside Template with event handlers inside the Template

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

I'm trying to **catch any click event inside the window** from inside a template `MyTemplate`, with something like this:

```
Template.MyTemplate.events({
  'click' : function(e) {
    console.log("click");
    // Here I need to access Template.instance()
    // ...
  }
});
```

But the code above doesn't works as I would like but **catches only clicks inside the template's DOM** and I can't get clicks outside the template.

Also, I would like to have the code inside the template itself, so something like `Template.body.events({ ... })` is not an option.

---

**WHAT I TRIED**

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486667/meteor-js-how-should-i-bind-events-to-the-window-in-meteor):

```
function clickEvent(event) {
  console.log('click');
  // Here I can access the right `Template.instance()` as `this`
  // thanks to the bind below
  // ...
}

Template.MyTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  // The `bind` give me the template instance inside the `clickEvent`
  // function
  $(document).on('click', clickEvent.bind(this));
});

Template.MyTemplate.onDestroyed(function () {
  $(document).off('click', clickEvent);
});
```

It works but seems like a workaround: I have all events inside `Template.MyTemplate.events({ ... })` while these ones are outside, I need to do a bind to get the template's instance and it uses JQuery to bind events and not Meteor itself.

So, is there no a simpler-way/Meteor-way to do that? Like some code that can go inside `Template.MyTemplate.events({ ... })`?

Comment: I think there is still some bugginess when binding to body from meteor, does this help? https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events

Comment: I don't that's possible, nor do I think the solution you mention is a workaround. I think your desire to keep the events "inside" the template is a little ill-guided. The event clearly is *not* inside the template, otherwise it would be caught, so you are merely trying to keep your code clean and retain the data context (which `bind` accomplished).

Comment: what about just wrapping your whole page in a template and attaching events to that?